# Printing Each Element In a List Double The Amount Of The Previous One

Tags: python, list, loops, nested-loops

Hello Im a bit of a noob .. Im trying to make the program print each element double the amount of the previous element starting with one time .. I found a solution but it seems clunky .. is there a better version .. here is the code .

```
a=['h','ha','hah','jaja','kkkkk']     
s=.5        
for x in range(len(a)):
    s=int(s*2)
    n=1
    for j in range (s):
        print(str(n)+str(a[x]))
        n+=1
```

Comment: Please clarify the expected output, it's not really obvious what "print each element double the amount of the previous element" means.

Comment: means it will print h once

Comment: ha twice and hah four times and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is readable and functional as is, but if you want to slim it down you can cut down some assignments by using [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), which is a python builtin that generates the incrementing variables s and n for you so you don't have to manage them yourself:

```
a=['h','ha','hah','jaja','kkkkk']     
for s, x in enumerate(range(len(a))):
    for n, j in enumerate(range(2**s)):
        print(str(n+1), str(a[x]))
```

Going by this approach means we're calculating powers by doing 2**s instead of doubling s every iteration, but this isn't a terribly material change. Also, if you pass multiple variables as separate parameters to print(), as print(a,b) instead of print(a + b), print() will fill in a space for you automatically which is nice for readability.

Comment: If an answer has what you want you can hit the checkmark on it to "close" the question as answered

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `pow()` function to calculate the next multiple of 2 on each iteration and use that to repeat `print()`:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
  for j in range(pow(2, i)):
    print(a[i])
```

Comment: the site recommends avoiding thanks .. but thanks :D